# Password migration

Tags: 8, users, migrations

I know that from Drupal 6 to Drupal 8 we needed to make the MD5 hash on migration, but I thought that from 7 to 8 it wasn't going to need any changes.

Drupal 8 Migrate examples doesn't mention anything about this, from what I saw, but I have a migration working here in my project for everything, and the passwords needs to be reset on Drupal 8 to work.

I think it may be related to the hash salt, but I'm not sure on how to check this.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is also being discussed here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2598038

Comment: For now, you might be able to do something like I mention in this post: [Migrating Drupal 7 users from site to site while preserving password hashes](http://www.jeffgeerling.com/blogs/jeff-geerling/migrating-drupal-7-users-site). I haven't tested with D8 yet, but it might work similarly if you manually migrate the hashes.

Comment: Any progress on this?